# Horizontal partitioning in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, smo

I'm wondering if its possible to automatically set up horizontal partitioning on a table, using a C# .NET class?

I'm sure this could be achieved using either Server Management Objects (SMO), or native T-SQL.

The horizontal partitioning would be by date, with one month per file.

**Update**

This scheme works amazingly well. My .NET app is is working perfectly:

- 90,000 rows/second insert speed on commodity hardware.
- 330 million rows, 52GB of data. No slowdown for inserts even when the database is this large.
- Each row is quite complex, with 30 columns.
- Clustered index (non-unique) on the date column, which has two benefits:

  - Selects are much faster (2 seconds vs. 120 seconds for a specific date).
  - The table is always sorted in date order, which is perfect as we are dealing with time series data and we want to retrieve data using cursors or bulk download.

If you want me to post the code I used, contact me by posting a question on this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell from the way you've worded your question if you are OK using T-Sql in your code and are just looking for an example, or you are trying to avoid T-Sql.  If it's the former than it would be something like this using [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx):

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("a connection string to your server");
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("", cn);

cn.Open();
```

The first step is to create a [partition function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx).  This is the guide for the partition that tells it what the boundaries of each partition are.  This example of breaking a datetime into individual months is right from Books Online.

```
cm.CommandText = "CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [myDateRangePF1] (datetime)
       AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20110201', '20110301', '20110401',
       '20110501', '20110601', '20110701', '20110801', 
       '20110901', '20111001', '20111101', '20111201')";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The next step is to [create a scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179854.aspx).  This maps the function that you created to your filegroup(s), one for each partition (i.e. month).  The filegroups must already exist so create them beforehand.

```
cm.CommandText = "CREATE PARTITION SCHEME myRangePS1 
                 AS PARTITION myRangePF1 TO 
                 (test1fg, test2fg, test3fg, test4fg, test5fg, test6fg, 
                 test7fg, test8fg, test9fg, test10fg, test11fg, test12fg)";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And then finally [creating a table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) on the filegroup(s):

```
cm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE PartitionTable (col1 int, col2 datetime) 
                 ON myRangePS1 (col2)";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

cn.Close();
```

And lastly, if the table you're trying to partition already exists then you're going to have to build the function, scheme and another table that looks just like it, and then move your data over to the new table.

Comment: I tried this, but it resulted in an error: "Invalid object name 'test1fg'.". Do I have to add a filegroup?

Comment: Yes, the filegroup(s) have to already exist.  Also, you don't HAVE to name them test1fg etc..   Check the links with each of the three steps as the books online does a good job of talking it all out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get it working. Good instructions, by the way.

Comment: That's what a database guy like me likes to hear... glad it's working like you hoped.

Comment: How do you update the partition function, if you need to increase the number of partitions for new data beyond 20111201 and also keep the old partitions around? I need to implement something similar, but in my case, new data will keep on getting added to the table, after the partitions have been created.

Comment: You should probably open a new question so the answer can get the benefit of the better Q/A editor.